How to change the text of Emails sent by sudo via mail_badpass?
Sudo can be configured - by default on Debian 12 - to send an email with the subject "*** SECURITY information" to the root user when someone tried to use sudo with a wrong password.
This behaviour is configured via the mail_badpass parameter.
While these emails are helpful IMHO, it's sad that they do not explain the service generating them.
Is it possible to change the email text or subject - for example "generated by sudo" (without recompiling)?

Did you bother reading the manual? It's documented.

Yes, and the behavior to send emails is not even mentioned here:
https://manpages.debian.org/testing/sudo/sudo.8.en.html
Now I learned that the magic is in sudoers manpage, ok.

Syntax (which is not clear in the manpage, read an example elsewhere):
Defaults  mailsub = "text"

It's always a good idea to start by reading the manual - and specifically the manual already installed on your machine. That way you know you're getting the right documentation for the right version of the tool installed on your host.
Here I get something very similar to this which both say:

tries to run a command via sudo, mail is sent to the proper authorities. The address used for such mail is configurable via the mailto Defaults entry (described later) and defaults to root.

So from sudo, you can switch the mail on or off (not helpful for your objective) and control where it goes. The latter provides a means for changing the content of the email. You didn't say what MTA you are using. Most provide support for milters. Here's an example used built-in capabilities of Postfix. Or you direct the email to handler which rewrites and resends the message to root.
But if you go on to read the rest of the man page, the versions here and on the link above say you can change the subject by setting the mailsub config in sudoers.
